# does fully removing itunes from MacOS cause problms?

Tags: macos, itunes

[image]

I get this when I try to do a simple delete (I know how to google and figure out how to remove the software). I want to know though, will removing iTunes break my system and why?

Comment: only thing I could think of is messing up default options for certian filetypes, but most of those quicktime should be able to open

Comment: That is what it says.

Comment: @Xavierjazz sure, but I'm trying to know why it would break things - I know deleting explorer would be problems on windoze becaue its the gui file explorer...iTunes is JUST a music player and linked library to their cloud profile of your music library.

Comment: "Why" is no part of your question above.

Comment: you're right, I've edited the question